# Build an hour booking calendar with events and hide not available hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, vuetify.js

For a new project, I have to built an hour booking calendar for doctors.
I'm looking for a plugin (js / vanilla / jquery / vuetify / react) that can respond to the following needs:

- have a weekly view of the current week (with a week pagination: w+1 / w+2 etc)
- display only available hours of the doctor (hide taken appointent / hourly)
- trigger an event from an hour pick

[Here is an exemple of exactly what I would like to achieve](https://www.doctolib.fr/medecin-generaliste/paris?availabilities=3)

What is the best plugin that can help me with this?
Also, doctors already have their own calendars. I will have to synchronise their calendar with mine, what is the best way to achieve this? How can I store all theses informations?

Don't hesitate to ask me questions

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have been searching searching for a plugin without any luck

Comment: Try fullcalendar : https://fullcalendar.io/ it fits really with your need.

Comment: I think, fullcalendar.io is what I'm looking for ( weekly toolbar + pagination, business hours, event trigger). I just need to check how to display/hide an event that has been takken. I will update what I will do in the question.  menett_a don't hesitate to create your own answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

I've had success with the appointment-picker npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/appointment-picker), it's very light weight.

Comment: Let me try it, look promising =)

Comment: Quick question, I need to combine a date with an appointment ex :
- Date : 12/12/2019
- Appointment : {"h":13,"m":0,"displayTime":"13:00"}
How did you manage it? 
Do you thinks it's best to modify the package by adding a date to it ex:  Appointment : {"h":13,"m":0,"displayTime":"13:00", "date":"12/12/2019"}
Or do I combine this package with an other weekly-calendar?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

The example that you linked is using React. Should you wish to go the React way without and not creating a bespoke solution then you can try [React Big Scheduler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-big-scheduler).

Here's the [demo](https://stephenchou1017.github.io/scheduler/#/).

It is inspired by FullCalendar. Keep in mind FullCalendar is paid depending on your [use](https://fullcalendar.io/purchase).